# Unit test using karma-jasmine with child process

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

Greeting,

I'm currently trying to create tests using karma-jasmine on a application using Angular and Electron.

I encountered a problem with simple-git which use child process and it seems to cause the issue :

"ERROR in ./node_modules/simple-git/src/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in 'C:\Users\Martin\Documents\Cours\Projet\Githarpon\git-harpon\node_modules\simple-git\src'
resolve 'child_process' in 'C:\Users\Martin\Documents\Cours\Projet\Githarpon\git-harpon\node_modules\simple-git\src'"

I then tried to Mock my service which use simple-git (GitService)

```
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [HomeComponent],
      imports: [
        FormsModule
      ],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: TranslateService,
          useClass: MockTranslateService
        },
        {
            provide: GitService,
            useClass: MockGitService
        },
        {
            provide: ElectronService,
            useClass: MockElectronService
        }
      ]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));
```

MockService :

```
import * as gitPromise from 'simple-git/promise';
import * as simpleGit from 'simple-git';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { ElectronService } from '../providers/electron.service';
import * as  GitUrlParse from 'git-url-parse';
import { ServiceResult } from '../models/ServiceResult';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

export class MockGitService {
}
```

And finally my karma.conf.js file :

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('karma-htmlfile-reporter'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma'),
    ],
    client:{
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, '../coverage'),
      reports: [ 'html', 'lcovonly' ],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
    htmlReporter: {
      outputFile: '../units/units.html'
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'html'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: true
  });
};
```

Any help could be very welcome